# Node.js httponly cookie desaparece cuando recargo la página

Tags: nodejs, express, cookies, nextjs

he creado una api en express.js y cuando hago la petición para el login, tengo implementado una función para crear un httponly cookie, y efectivamente cuando hago la petición se crea. El problema viene cuando recargo la página, la cookie desaparece automáticamente y no entiendo el por qué. He intentado buscar soluciones pero no la encuentro. Para el frontend utilizo Next.js y aquí les dejo el código en express.js donde creo la cookie y el resultado en el navegador:

```
res.cookie('cookie', `Bearer ${token}`, {
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite:'none',
    path: '/', 
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development"
});
```

CORS:

```
app.use(cors({ origin: 'http://localhost:3000', credentials: true }));
```

[image: captura]

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español. Por favor traduce tu pregunta

Comment: también el titulo